# Ansible: Merge list to new list with item.key and item.value

Tags: ansible

Example:

**file: storages.yml**

```yml
---
storages:
- storageA
- storageB
```

**file: storageA_list_vv.yml**

```yml
---
vv:
- storageA_lun01
- storageA_lun02
```

**file: storageB_list_vv.yml**

```yml
---
vv:
- storageB_lun01
```

**Expected new list: vvset.yml**

```yml
---
vvset:
- key: serverA
  value: serverA_lun01
- key: serverA
  value: serverA_lun02
- key: serverB
  value: serverB_lun01
```

Appreciate your guidance and advise on how to combine three list `storages.yml`, `storageA_list_vv.yml` and `storageB_list_vv.yml` into new list `vvset.yml`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi debug, welcome to SO. This is not a "write code for me" website, so you will need to edit your question and include the code you have tried so far, and any error messages that it is producing. You should read the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page, and pay especial attention to the [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) section. Good luck

Comment: @mdaniel is right. Post your code. There are many options on how to do it. To avoid paths leading nowhere, see the steps in my answer as hints. You might want to optimize it.

Answer (score 1):

Below is the step by step "brute-force" approach. [Custom filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/developing_plugins.html#filter-plugins) would make it much simpler.

1. Read the files and create the list of all items

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        vv: "{{ vv|default([]) +
                (lookup('file', item)|from_yaml).values()|list }}"
      loop:
        - storageA_list_vv.yml
        - storageB_list_vv.yml
    - debug:
        var: vv|flatten
```

gives

```yaml
  vv|flatten:
  - storageA_lun01
  - storageA_lun02
  - storageB_lun01
```

2. Extract the data

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        vvset1: "{{ vvset1|default([]) +
                    [{'index': index, 'lun': lun}] }}"
      loop: "{{ vv|flatten }}"
      vars:
        index: "{{ item.split('_').0|
                   regex_replace('^storage(.*)$', '\\1')}}"
        lun: "{{ item.split('_').1 }}"
    - debug:
        var: vvset1
```

gives

```yaml
  vvset1:
  - index: A
    lun: lun01
  - index: A
    lun: lun02
  - index: B
    lun: lun01
```

3. Use [groupby](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/master/templates/#groupby)

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        vvset2: "{{ vvset2|default([]) +
                    [{'index': item.0, 'lun': item.1|map(attribute='lun')|list}] }}"
      loop: "{{ vvset1|groupby('index') }}"
    - debug:
        var: vvset2
```

gives

```yaml
  vvset2:
  - index: A
    lun:
    - lun01
    - lun02
  - index: B
    lun:
    - lun01
```

4. Use [subelements](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/lookup/subelements.html#subelements-traverse-nested-key-from-a-list-of-dictionaries)

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        vvset3: "{{ vvset3|default([]) +
                    [{'key': key, 'value': val}] }}"
      with_subelements:
        - "{{ vvset2 }}"
        - lun
      vars:
        key: "{{ 'server' ~ item.0.index }}"
        val: "{{ 'server' ~ item.0.index ~ '_' ~ item.1  }}"
    - debug:
        var: vvset3
```

gives

```yaml
  vvset3:
  - key: serverA
    value: serverA_lun01
  - key: serverA
    value: serverA_lun02
  - key: serverB
    value: serverB_lun01
```